# SQL Server select with multiple groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables describing users and their payments:

```
CREATE TABLE test_users
(id int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
name varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE test_payments
(id int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
user_id int NOT NULL,
money money NOT NULL,
date datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO test_users (name) 
VALUES ('john');

INSERT INTO test_users (name) 
VALUES ('peter');

INSERT INTO test_payments (user_id, money, date)
VALUES (1, $1, CONVERT(datetime, '15.12.2012'));

INSERT INTO test_payments (user_id, money, date)
VALUES (1, $2, CONVERT(datetime, '16.12.2012'));

INSERT INTO test_payments (user_id, money, date)
VALUES (2, $1, CONVERT(datetime, '16.12.2012'));

INSERT INTO test_payments (user_id, money, date)
VALUES (2, $3, CONVERT(datetime, '17.12.2012'));

INSERT INTO test_payments (user_id, money, date)
VALUES (1, $1, CONVERT(datetime, '19.12.2012'));
```

Table test_users:

```
id  name
-------------
1   john
2   peter
```

Table test_payments:

```
id  user_id money   last_activity
---------------------------------------
1   1   1.0000  2012-12-15
2   1   2.0000  2012-12-16
3   2   1.0000  2012-12-16
4   2   3.0000  2012-12-17
5   1   1.0000  2012-12-19
```

I need to make a users statistic which will show me :

1. username
2. total fee for a period of time
3. the date of the last
   user's activity (general, not for a time period).

For example taking the period 15-18.12.12 I expect the following results:

```
name    total    last_activity
--------------------------------
peter   $4       2012-12-17
john    $3       2012-12-19
```

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT u.*, SUM(p.money) total, MAX(p.date) last_activity
FROM test_users u
JOIN test_payments p
ON u.id= p.user_id
WHERE p.date BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '15.12.2012') AND CONVERT(datetime, '18.12.2012')
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

but getting wrong result for last_activity as it is also in the date range:

```
id  name    total   last_activity
--------------------------------
2   peter   4.0000  2012-12-17
1   john    3.0000  2012-12-16
```

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a couple of other answers popped up while I worked on mine, but here it is anyhow.  There is a working sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14808/6

Basically, you need a query to pull the max date regardless of the date range.  I chose to do this as a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  u.name,
  SUM(IsNull(money,0)) as TotalMoneyInRange,
  (SELECT max(date) FROM test_payments where user_id = u.id) AS LastPaymentOverAll
FROM test_users AS u
LEFT JOIN test_payments AS p
ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE 
  p.date IS NULL OR
  p.date between 
  CAST('12-11-2012' AS datetime) --range begin
  and 
  CAST('12-16-2012' as datetime) --range end
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

Comment: Here's another version that uses CTEs to get each of your aggregates, and then joins that up to the complete list of users for the final result.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5c2b/1

Comment: Yet another that uses CROSS APPLYs to get the aggregates.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5c2b/5

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the condition from the `where` clause to a `case` statement:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,
      SUM(case when p.date BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '15.12.2012') AND CONVERT(datetime, '18.12.2012')
               then p.money
          end) total,
      MAX(p.date) last_activity
FROM test_users u JOIN
     test_payments p
     ON u.id= p.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

If you only want users who had a payment in that period, then you can include:

```
having total is not null
```

If you want the NULL values to appear as 0 instead of NULL, then include `else 0` in the case statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use subqueries to get the result:

```
SELECT u.*, total, last_activity
FROM test_users u
JOIN
(
  select sum(money) total, user_id
  from test_payments
  WHERE date BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '2012-12-15') 
    AND CONVERT(datetime, '2012-12-18')
  group by user_id
) p
  ON u.id= p.user_id
inner join 
(
  select user_id, max(date) last_activity
  from test_payments
  group by user_id
) p1
  on p.user_id = p1.user_id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be4c1/10)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a sub query for the MAX date that doesn't have the WHERE clause like so:

```
SELECT 
  u.*
  ,SUM(p.money) total
  ,a.max_date last_activity
FROM test_users u
  INNER JOIN test_payments p ON u.id = p.user_id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(date) AS max_date 
              FROM test_payments 
              GROUP BY user_id) a ON u.id = a.user_id
WHERE p.date BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '15.12.2012') AND CONVERT(datetime, '18.12.2012')
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, a.max_date
ORDER BY total DESC;
```